# How can I make sure that the content in my bootstrap container is never larger than the container itself

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

What I am trying to do is have 3 rows in one container. The first one is the header. The last one the footer. In the middle row there should be two columns. The left column should contain many cards where you can scroll through. I tried many things to make the elements fit the 100vh of the container but it didn't work. So in short, I want to have a scrollbar in the left column in row 2 but nowhere else. Everything should fit on the display.

Here is my code: https://codepen.io/PrestigeEis/pen/ExbqWpR

```
<div class="container-fluid vh-100">
      <div class="row" id="row1">
        <div class="col-3 border titleCol">DEM Units consumption</div>
        <div class="col-9 border titleCol">Detail Page</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" id="row2">
        <div id="customerList" class="col-3">
          <div class="card customerCard">CustomerA</div>
          <div class="card customerCard">CustomerB</div>
          <div class="card customerCard">CustomerC</div>
          <div class="card customerCard">CustomerD</div>
          <div class="card customerCard">CustomerE</div>
          <div class="card customerCard">CustomerF</div>
          <div class="card customerCard">CustomerG</div>
          <div class="card customerCard">CustomerH</div>
        </div>
        <div id="detailPage" class="col-9"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" id="row3">
        <div class="col-3 border footerCol"></div>
        <div class="col-9 border gap-2 footerCol">
          <button type="button" id="safeBtn" class="btn btn-primary">
            Save
          </button>
          <button type="button" id="cancelBtn" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
            Cancel
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

AND CSS:

```
html,body, #root {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #9b9a9a;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #8c8c8c;
}

#customerList {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 0px;
  max-height: inherit;
}



#detailPage {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 0px;
}

.customerCard {
  min-height: 150px;
  border-radius: 0%;
}

.titleCol {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-height: 45px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footerCol {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-height: 45px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: end;
}

#safeBtn {
  background-color: #0a6cd1;
}
#safeBtn:hover {
  background-color: #085caf;
}

#cancelBtn {
  color: #085caf;
  border-color: white;
}

#cancelBtn:hover {
  color: #085caf;
  border-color: #085caf;
  background-color: #ebf5fe;
}

#row1{
  max-height: 10vh;
}

#row2{
  max-height: 88.2vh;
}

#row3{
  max-height: 10vh;
}
```

Comment: did you try adding 
display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100%;
to the outermost parent

Answer (score 0):

So it would be best perhaps to put your header inside `<header>` tags, then have all your content inside one or more `container`s and have the footer inside `<footer>` tags.

```
<header>
   Logo and menu etc
</header>

<div class="container">
   Main page content
</container>

<footer>
   Foot-menu copyright blurb etc.
</footer>
```

You can then add 2 columns inside the container and a row.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <!-- full width on small screens and left column on mediums screens and above -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <!-- full width on small screens and right column on mediums screens and above -->
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

To get a scroll bar on one of those columns You just need to control any overflow.

HTML

```
 <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 card-column">
```

CSS

```
.card-column{
overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: if i add header and footer i get a scrollbar so it didnt work for me

Comment: Well, beware. `Header` and `footer` are generally good practice along with the other specific tags such as `article` for example.